# Find pdf of z if $Z = X^2+Y^2$ given joint pdf of X,Y, need help understanding the solution

Tags: probability, statistics

Hi I am learning probability on my own, and came across this problem online, find pdf of of z given

$$f_{xy} = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\exp(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2})$$

$$Z = X^2+Y^2$$

The solution uses

$ \sin^2{\phi} +\cos^2{\phi} = 1 $

$ x = r\cos(\phi)$

$ y = r\sin(\phi) $

$ z = x^2 + y^2 = r^2\cos^2(\phi) +  r^2\sin^2(\phi) = r^2$

to get

$f_{r\phi} = \frac{r}{2\pi\sigma^2}\exp(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}) $

this is where I got lost, where does the r in the $\frac{r}{2\pi\sigma^2}$ come from?
This solution explains "the factor of r is from the differential area relationship $dxdy = rdrd\phi$", but where does dxdy come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $R=f(X,Y)$ and $\Phi=g(X,Y)$ with $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\phi=arctan(\dfrac{y}{x})$. Then the joint density function $$f_{R\Phi}(r,\phi) = |J|f_{XY}(r,\phi)$$

Where Jacobian is $|J|=$$
\begin{vmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}&\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}\\
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}\\
\end{vmatrix}
= \begin{vmatrix} cos(\phi) & -rsin(\phi) \\ sin(\phi) & rcos(\phi)\end{vmatrix} =r$.

$$f_{R\Phi}(r,\phi)  = r \dfrac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}e^{-\dfrac{(x^2+y^2)}{2\sigma^2}} =  \dfrac{r}{2\pi\sigma^2}e^{-\dfrac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$

Comment: Jacobian of $f_{xy}$?

Comment: why is $f_{r\phi}(r,\phi) = |J|f_{xy}(r,\phi)$? What's this method called?

Comment: This method is called Transformations involving multiple functions of random variables. $J$ is called Jacobian of the transformation.

Comment: I believe you meant $r = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$. To complete the solution,
$$f_Z(z) = \frac {\pi f_{R \Phi}(\sqrt z, \phi)} {\sqrt z} =
\frac {e^{-z/(2 \sigma^2)}} {2 \sigma^2}.$$

Comment: @Maxim yes. Thanks

Comment: @Maxim where does the $\pi$ come from?

Comment: @user14042 We have
$$f_Z(z) =
\frac d {dz} \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{\sqrt z} f_{R \Phi}(r, \phi) dr d \phi,$$
and we can apply Leibniz's integral rule instead of evaluating the inner integral.